# How do I get my last 30 days of Azure cost from the CLI?

Tags: azure

I want to pull the last 30 days of cost per resource group using the AZ CLI.

I'd really like it as a value or JSON blob, not a file dumped to a storage container.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve your last 30 days of Azure cost using the Command-Line Interface (CLI), execute the following Azure CLI command:

```
az consumption usage list --query "[?usageEnd >= 'start_date' && usageEnd <= 'end_date']" --output table
```

Replace 'start_date' and 'end_date' with the desired date range. This command fetches consumption data within the specified range and displays it in a tabular format. It's a quick and efficient way to obtain cost insights for the last 30 days directly from the CLI.

Comment: Add the info as text, not image!!!

Comment: This helps but I need to do it per Resource Group. I'll try messing around with the filters and see if I can figure it out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I did create a CLI tool to fetch the cost from Azure and output it to different formats. Maybe that suits your needs. You can find it here: https://github.com/mivano/azure-cost-cli

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it - we don't have full access to the account (it's the .gov!) but I'll give it a go.